# Choosing more options with intval( $row)

Tags: php, logical-operators

I am trying to have this function working with 1 of 3 or more results (like "Yes, NO, Why not, Maybe" but i am not able to find a solution

```
$row['Funcionario'] = ( intval( $row['Funcionario']) == 1) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

The code above only gives me 2 possibilities: 
Yes (`$row['Funcionario'] == 1` ) or No (`$row['Funcionario'] != 1`)
How do I show `Why not` if `$row['Funcionario'] == 2` or `Maybe` if `$row['Funcionario'] == 3`?

Comment: you can use multiple nested if/else instead of using the ternary operator.. or use a switch

Comment: you should use [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for multiple checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statements

```
switch ($row['Funcionario']) {
    case 1:
        echo 'This code will be executed if $row[\'Funcionario\'] is 1';
        break;
    case 2:
        echo 'This code will be executed if $row[\'Funcionario\'] is 2';
        break;
    case "Yes":
        echo 'This code will be executed if $row[\'Funcionario\'] is Yes';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'This code will be executed if $row[\'Funcionario\'] is not any of the values before
}
```

You can replace the values after `case` with anything you want, and the following code until the next `break` will be executed if `$row['Funcionario']` is that value.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way:

Define an array...

```
$answers = ["No", "Yes", "Why not", "Maybe"];
```

And get from it...

```
$row['Functionario'] = $answers[$row['Functionario']];
```

If the array is one-time use (ie. not used by other fields that may have these values), you could shorten it to:

```
$row['Functionario'] = ["No", "Yes", "Why not", "Maybe"][$row['Functionario']];
```

Readability may vary. Consider adding whitespace and/or comments to explain what's going on.